# Spring security plugin not throwing events

Tags: security, events, grails, plugins, registering

I am in the process of migrating to spring security plugin from acegi plugin.Currently working on grails environment. I am facing a weird issue as my authentication success event and authentication bad credentials event does not throw at all.I added println statements in the callback in config.groovy and also through listeners.However i can catch events like InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent. Please do reply if you have gone through the same issue

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Chapter 5 of the [user guide](http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/) you need to enable events with "useSecurityEventListener" and configure one or more callback closures, e.g.:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   println "onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent: $e"
}

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   println "onAbstractAuthenticationFailureEvent: $e"
}

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   println "onAuthenticationSuccessEvent: $e"
}

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onAuthenticationSwitchUserEvent = { e, appCtx ->
   println "onAuthenticationSwitchUserEvent: $e"
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried doing all these but the problem was these events were never invoked at all. I was able to receive only onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent . I went through the spring source code and there in AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter class they just throw the onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent  on successful authentication, on authentication failure they just call the failure handler.Do i need to add handlers instead of listening to events? or do i need to inject provider Managers? I didn't add any provider manager thinking that the plugin for grails would do it for me :(

Comment: Hmmm, looks like things changed between Spring Security 2 and 3. Please create an issue at http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS under the Grails-Spring-Security-Core component and I'll see what I can do for the next release.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the follow up.We logged a bug as you said http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILSPLUGINS-2248

Comment: I've release version 0.4.1 of the plugin with this fix.

Answer (score 0):

The provider manager uses the Null event publisher by default. We can inject the default authentication event publisher in resources.groovy.

`defaultEventPublisher(DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher)
  /** authenticationManager  */
  authenticationManager(ProviderManager) {
    authenticationEventPublisher = ref('defaultEventPublisher')
    providers = listOfProviders
  }`