# Changing last login date in Grails with Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security

In my `Config.groovy` I used:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useSecurityEventListener = true

grails.plugins.springsecurity.onInteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent = { e, appCtx ->
    User.withTransaction {
        def user = User.findById(appCtx.springSecurityService.principal.id)
        if(!user.isAttached())
            user.attach()
        user.lastLoginDate = new Date()
        user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    }
}
```

My User domain has this field and I don't get any errors while logging in, however, the field is not updated.

I tried [debugging everything](http://pastebin.com/9ciZg7j4) from `org.hibernate` but I couldn't find any `update`or other relevant statements.

Is there anything else I need to add anywhere in order to get this working?

For the record:

- Grails 1.3.7
- Spring Security Core 1.1.2
- Hibernate 1.3.7

Comment: I'm using Grails 1.3.6 and SSC 1.1.2, with almost exactly the same code as you and for me it's working - so I'm thinking there must be something else that is the problem. Eg the user cannot be saved due to errors or something similar... The only thing I have that you don't is that I catch "OptimisticLockingFailureException" and then do a User.merge(user), but I doubt that should be the cause of your problems.

Comment: I was able to solve it, actually really really stupid. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, the answer was plain simple. I had forgot the package name so it wouldn't find `User`.

So this one worked if your `User` object is in the package `org.test`:

```
org.test.User.withTransaction {
      def user = org.test.User.get(appCtx.springSecurityService.principal.id)
      user.lastLoginDate = new Date()
      user.save(failOnError: true)
}
```

Comment: Some unrelated suggestions. One is you can remove the attach logic - you're loading the instance in a transaction, so it'll always be attached. And you can omit 'flush: true' since a transaction always flushes. Also never use findById() - use get().

Answer (score 0):

What version r u using of spring security core?? Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3130459/spring-security-plugin-not-throwing-events) and its relevant answer given by the author of spring security.... May be you need to upgrade spring security version?

**:: UPDATE ::**

[This post](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Problem-setting-lastLogin-on-User-using-SecurityConfig-td1355811.html) have the same issue as yours, hopefully you will get solution by looking into it...

Comment: I'm using 1.1.2 - the question mentioned v0.4.1 fixing this last summer.

Comment: can you try out by adding active=true at the top ? as mentioned here : http://www.grails.org/AcegiSecurity+Plugin+-+Acegi+Events..

Comment: I tried this, moved everything to `SecurityConfig.groovy`, but no luck either.

Comment: you don't need SecurityConfig.groovy, as it was with acegi plugin (earlier version), using spring security core, you can do it inside Config.groovy only...

Comment: So you are saying I **can** do it inside `Config.groovy` or I **must** do it there? I know the thread you linked to, that's where I got the code from initially ;)

Comment: You must need to do it inside Config.groovy only... Read this link : http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/single.html#7%20Events

Comment: Ok. I also read this file, that's where I got the other code from ;) It just doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: May be Burt Beckwith could help you now. :)

Comment: I hope so! Burt, where are you? :P

Comment: @Nirmal I was finally able to solve it. Thanks anyway for your support!